# How can I test a mobile website for an Android device, if I'm using a mac?

Tags: android, mobile, mobile-browser, browser-testing

I'm creating a website and I've been testing in different browsers, but not android devices, because I don't normally have access. Someone looked at the site on an Android phone (using the default web browser and chrome) and one of the pages is not displaying correctly.   My index page is just a full screen image, but on the Android device, the image is pushed up and the bottom half of the screen is white.  I can't figure out why this would be different on an Android phone. How can I test my site to see how it would react on an Android phone?

Answer (score 2):

You can download `android studio` from [google](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html)

Since it just needs java, it should work on OSX also. In the studio you would be able to lauch different emulated devices, fully connected to the network.

The download is huge and the setup is relatively easy. And it's flexible, when it comes to the different android versions, devices and screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Download Android Studio and use the emulator
Or Genymotion is another emulator you could use. I have not used it myself, but it is probably the most popular emulator out side of the official one in android studio.